# Executing two programs concurrently

Tags: bash, shell

I have two programs I need to start in a concrete order:

1. `./server`
2. `./client`

I want to write a shell script that is running those two programs inside a for loop (script domain is benchmarking the application). For that reason I need to have the `client` call blocking and the `server` call async, but I also need to explicitly kill the `server` after the `client` has returned (so the `server` can be started fresh in the next iteration).

What is the easiest way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
server &
PID=$!
client
kill $PID
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps start the server up and store its PID `$!`.

```
#!/bin/sh

./server & storepid="$!"
./client
kill "$storepid"
```

Comment: `if [ "$storeret" = 0 ]` can be written simply as `if $storeret`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I doubt it! `if $storeret` will try to execute the command obtained by expanding the variable `storeret`… and I doubt you have an executable called `0` in your `PATH`.

Comment: Hmm, after your edits this is fundamentally identical to the other, accepted answer. Maybe just delete this?